# PC-Lint on IAR not understanding std::atomic<>

Tags: c++, iar, pc-lint

I have a similar construct to this snippet in my code

```cpp
namespace
{
   std::atomic<bool> flag(true);
}

void Allocator::deallocate(void* p, const size_t n) //lint !e715 suppress "named parameter 'n' not referenced"
{
   if (!flag) { //lint !e774 suppress "boolean condition for 'if' always evaluates to 'false'"
      freed += n; 

      // more code where variable flag may get toggled
   }
}
```

The lint suppressions are currently required on IAR analysis only.
It's probably because the IAR header for `std::atomic` throws PC-Lint. As a result PC-Lint considers variable `flag` as something that never changes value, even when the code in this file does (see code comment).
Collaterally, it deems that variable `n` is never referenced because it is inside "unreachable" code.

This code is x-compiled and no static analysis for other platforms reports these same warnings and errors against this code, suggesting that the root of the problem lies with IAR's header for `std::atomic<>`.

I have - as an experiment - replaced the `std::atomic<bool>` with a plain `bool`. I am then able to remove all the PC-Lint suppressions successfully.

Is there a way I can configure PC-Lint in such a manner that it interprets any instance of `std::atomic<T>` as just `T`?